# tcp without Winsock

Tags: c#, tcp, winsock

How can i work with tcp connection without Winsock or another external binary?

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: i like to have full controll on my programs or atleast know how it works, since i'm not ready go step down to lower levels of programming.. i'm asking how to do it with C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using C#, you should just use the [System.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.aspx) and [System.Net.Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.aspx) namespaces.

These isolate you from working with Winsock directly (although they are based on Windows Sockets internally, at least on Windows).

For example, the [TcpClient class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) provides a TCP Client connection, and has been supported in C# in every version of the .NET Framework.  There is absolutely no reason not to use these classes if you want to work with sockets.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what extra control over TCP you need. If you find it hard to troubleshoot TCP connection issues, you can always utilize System.Net tracing and Microsoft Network Monitor.

System.Net is by far the best library you can use.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=983b941d-06cb-4658-b7f6-3088333d062f&displaylang=en

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947285